# session API in Opera empty on start

Tags: opera-extension

Session API in Chrome gives tabs from previous session (until new one is written)
but Opera doesn't.
Is there any way to get previous session tabs on Opera start?
(with JS ofc)

Comment: Opera also supports sessions API but I see it's not documented.

Comment: @ŁukaszBendig yea, it supports, but with difference that it doesn't give previous session like Chrome does... any other way to get previous session tabs/windows in Opera?